# Select Dataframe records with multiple conditions with a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, multiple-conditions

I have a list of text.

```
thislist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
```

I have a dataframe as below

```
d = {'fruit ': [apple, orange, pear, mango, banana, cherry], 'price': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'status':['y','y','n','n','y','n'}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

My list and dataframe could be dynamic thus I did't want to select my dataframe by hardcoding the variables such as `df['fruit'] == 'apple'`

How can I write in such a way to select my rows with a dynamic list?
example

```
df2 = (df1[(df1['fruits']==thislist[x]) & 
(df1['status'] == 'y')])
```

where x will run along the thislist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you want `isin`:

```
df[df['fruit'].isin(thislist) & (df['status'] == 'y')]

   fruit   price status
0   apple      1      y
4  banana      5      y
```